# different between static:: and $this-> and which syntax i should use?

Tags: php, static, this

I have some code:

```
class a {
    public static function getCl() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public function test() {
        static::getCl();
    }
}
class b extends a {
    public static function getCl() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
$testClass = new b();
$testClass->test();
```

and this result : b. Then i try this:

```
class a {
    public static function getCl() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->getCl();
    }
}
class b extends a {
    public static function getCl() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
$testClass = new b();
$testClass->test();
```

this result is still b. I already know the different between static:: and self:: but can someone show me what is the different between static:: and $this-> in my code. Which one should i use?

Comment: In your context, the main difference is that using $this you can create object chaining but with static keyword it is not possible.

Comment: `static::` can be used on static methods/properties only, whereas `$this->` can be used on either.

Comment: @silkfire: Acoording to manual, a property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object

Answer (score 0):

Your context will produce the same result.

Here is simply description about both.

**static**:- refers [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)  As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP implements a feature called late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance.

Static references to the current class like self:: or **CLASS** are resolved using the class in which the function belongs, as in where it was defined:

While Late static bindings tries to solve that limitation by introducing a keyword that references the class that was initially called at runtime. Basically, a keyword that would allow you to reference child class from parent class method. It was decided not to introduce a new keyword but rather use static that was already reserved.

**$this**:- refers current object.

Once inside an object's function, you have complete access to its variables, but to set them you need to be more specific than just using the variable name you want to work with. To properly specify you want to work with a local variable, you need to use the special $this variable, which PHP always sets to point to the object you are currently working with.

Comment: Not really. Given that both approaches produce the same result (without any warning/notice) what's the reasoning for preferring one over the other? There are (at least) two things you could show: a) `$this->` produces a different/unexpected outcome compared to `self::`; I wonder if you could do that in php (possible, but adhoc I can't). b) it becomes very, very confusing for developers reading the code. E.g. for using object.staticMethod() in Java both is true (that's why the compiler generates a warning; but only a warning; something worth exploring as well).

Comment: @VolkerK: Totally agree with you. Existing context produce the same result. Acording to me main difference is that we can create object chaining using $this but not with static keyword.